# Proper use of UIApplicationMain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiapplication, main-method

I have decided to load my views programmatically, so putting:

```
int ret = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Would not work. I do have a ViewController and an AppDelegate, though. What would be the proper use of UIApplicationMain to use a ViewController and an AppDelegate.
PS I am NOT using XCode or Interface Builder, I am developing on the toolchain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This function is declared as](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW7)

```
int UIApplicationMain (
   int argc,
   char *argv[],
   NSString *principalClassName,
   NSString *delegateClassName
);
```

Since you did not subclass UIApplication, pass `nil` to the 3rd argument. But you have a custom UIApplicationDelegate. So pass its class name to the 4th argument.

```
int retval = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of subclassing UIApplication?

Comment: @Mohit: To replace some default behavior of UIApplication, e.g. `sendAction:to:from:forEvent:`.

Comment: Replace @"AppDelegate" with NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]) to avoid the magic string in case you ever rename AppDelegate to something else.

Comment: @George Hm.... you probably meant to write `[appDelegate class]`, unless you capitalize your variable names. Or am I missing something? Surely you don't want the class name there but rather, the variable name.

Comment: @MattN. `AppDelegate` *is* the class name in his example. ;-) [Yes, this is a comment from the far future. :-p ]