# Thread 1:Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT error code

Tags: iphone, ios4, error-handling, sigabrt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [thread 1 program received signal SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085556/thread-1-program-received-signal-sigabrt)

```
<UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

it is the me this error `Thread 1:Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT".` beside the line 
`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

```
2011-11-10 20:49:47.695 AVMultiPlayer[14036:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3102a8bf 0x381cf1e5 0x3102a7b9 0x3102a7db 0x3803e06f 0x3803e00b 0x2c79 0x2a0d 0x30f84435 0x32fdf9eb 0x32fdf9a7 0x32fdf985 0x32fdf6f5 0x32fdf321 0x32fde485 0x32fddf01 0x32fc44ed 0x32fc3d2d 0x33bafe13 0x30ffe553 0x30ffe4f5 0x30ffd343 0x30f804dd 0x30f803a5 0x33baefed 0x32ff2743 0x2219 0x21d8)
terminate called throwing an exceptionkill
quit
```

that is what the output box is displaying