# Thread 1:Program received signal

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory, sigabrt, nsautoreleasepool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [thread 1 program received signal SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085556/thread-1-program-received-signal-sigabrt)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

it is giving me a error when i run it on my device

```
2011-11-10 14:59:43.487 AVMultiPlayer[13554:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3102a8bf 0x381cf1e5 0x3102a7b9 0x3102a7db 0x3803e06f 0x3803e00b 0x2dc9 0x2b5d 0x30f84435 0x32fdf9eb 0x32fdf9a7 0x32fdf985 0x32fdf6f5 0x32fdf321 0x32fde485 0x32fddf01 0x32fc44ed 0x32fc3d2d 0x33bafe13 0x30ffe553 0x30ffe4f5 0x30ffd343 0x30f804dd 0x30f803a5 0x33baefed 0x32ff2743 0x25b5 0x2574)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

that is the output code it is sending be

```
0x0000222c  <+0060>  str    r0, [sp, #4] <------ Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT".
```

that is the error it is giving me

```
- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [theAudio setDelegate: self];
        [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
        [theAudio play];
    [path retainCount];




}

- (void)playLooped:(NSString *)aSound {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [theAudio setDelegate: self];
        // loop indefinitely
        [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
        [theAudio setVolume:1.0];
        [theAudio play];
    [theAudio release];


}
```

how do i fix this it runs on the simulator with no problems but when i try it on my device it gives me a error my program has 4 views the other 3 work perfectly except for the last one my program is just buttons that make sound